# Custom Button is not inflating correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

This might be very simple problem.. but I just could not figure this out the issue.

I just extended the MaterialButton like

```
class MyButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

And put that in the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <com.example.myapplication.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the output is
[image]

It becomes a TextView. I have added material library in the gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Any help! Thanks

Comment: `defStyleAttr = R.attr.materialButtonStyle` – You've got the wrong default for that constructor parameter.

Comment: worked like a magic. thanks @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyButton tag with this one

```
<com.example.myapplication.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the default value for defStyleAttr to `R.attr.materialButtonStyle`:

```
class MyButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.materialButtonStyle,
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```